# Unity: How to find a empty hole in a wall for player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm trying to figure out simple custom 2D physics for platformer. At the moment I'm using ray casts to figure out collision between the player and map. However using ray cast has some problems. For example, if the player is falling (has somewhat high downwards velocity) its unable to pick up holes in the wall because it moves past them due to going too far down to be detected as empty space.

One solution is to move to tile based system instead of using ray casts but I would preferably not to do so.

So I'm wondering is there some kinda solution to figure out empty holes in wall, even small edge ones without huge performance impact.

High quality drawn illustration, assume leftwards velocity:

[image: 1]

Comment: Raycasts are not as expensive as people imagine, just raycast the hell out of that wall (for positions you expect in the future, based on current velocity)

Comment: @zambari So if the block height could be as small as 0.1 I should do like 30 raycasts when the vecolty is 3?

Comment: Can you post some code, I have a feeling that this is a problem with the length of the raycast, not the amount of rays. You should get decent accuracy with three raycasts spaced evenly, from the bottom of the player downwards. See this video for a guide on 2d raycast controllers : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PlT44xr0iW0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Physics2D.BoxCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.BoxCast.html) is how I would tackle this. It does what you expect, instead of a ray it calculates as if a full box was traversing the distance.

Usage is very similar to raycasting. Example:

```cs
public Collider2D mainCollider;
public Vector2 velocity;

void Update() {
    Vector2 origin = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
    Vector2 size = mainCollider.bounds.size;
    Vector2 direction = velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    float maxDist = velocity.magnitude;

    var hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(origin, size, 0, direction, maxDepth);

    if (hit == null) {
        transform.position += direction;
    } else {
        transform.position += direction.normalized * hit.distance;
    }
}
```

If boxes are not your taste, there's also a [`Physics2D.CapsuleCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CapsuleCast.html) and [`Physics2D.CircleCast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.CircleCast.html).

Comment: I ended up doing box cast to the side, find the first place where I want to stop and then box cast down to figure out where to land (and also stretching the last box cast as the left over velocity)